# Is there any way to access inverted index on sql server full text search

Tags: sql-server, indexing, full-text-search

I would like to get "content" () of full text search index as described in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverted_index and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SQL_Server#Full_Text_Search_Service. Content - name of word and occurences

This question is related with my previous question without answer [Dynamic tags generation from sql server database using full text search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3475104/dynamic-tags-generation-from-sql-server-database-using-full-text-search)

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server 2008 you can query the `sys.dm_fts_index_keywords` and `sys.dm_fts_index_keywords_by_document` [table valued functions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc721269%28SQL.100%29.aspx) to get this information.

For previous versions I think this is much less easily accessible (if at all)

Comment: Yes it works if sql server is 2008 but on production env. we've got 2005 ... I am still looking for solution.