# Find Unique Words in One or More Columns?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, tags

I'm looking at implementing tags in my ASP.NET website. After looking at several algorithms, I'm leaning towards having a couple of database columns that contain one or more tag words. I will then use full-text search to locate rows with specified tags.

All of this seems pretty straight forward except for one thing: I need to be able to generate a list of available tags, which the user can select from.

I know I can write a C# program to build the list of available tags, and then run it once every week or so, but I was just wondering if there's any SQL-method for doing stuff like this more efficiently.

Also, I can't help but notice that the words will be extracted anyway as part of building the full-text index. I don't suppose there's any way to access that information?

Comment: What version are you on? If SQL Server 2008 this querying of the full text indexes is possible but why are you storing multiple tags per column? This doesn't sound normalised. Will you ever need to search for all entities with a specific tag? If so how were you planning on doing that? Using `LIKE '%tagname%'` or something?

Comment: Yes, SQL Server 2008. I'm still fleshing it out but, in my case, it may be helpful to have tags for various things like "platform", "language", etc. Using `LIKE '%tagname%'` would be a great idea if I didn't care anything about performance. As indicated, I plan to use a full-text search.

Comment: I was in no way suggesting that was a good idea I was just wondering what your plan was. This sounds a pretty bad idea to me. Doing a task like renaming a tag will be pretty painful for example also are you aware of all the vagaries of full text search and dealing with special characters that you might want to include in tag names? (Sounds like your tags are programming oriented? - I'm not sure how a tag like `C#` would be full text indexed)

Comment: @Martin: Those are all valid points. I could instead enter C# as CS or something like that. I recall reading somewhere that this is how SO stored tags (I forget some of the details). I'd have to run some tests but it seems like it would be more efficient in many ways that a many-to-many join, which is basically the other option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't how I'd choose to structure this but to answer the actual question...

In SQL Server 2008 you can query the `sys.dm_fts_index_keywords` and `sys.dm_fts_index_keywords_by_document` [table valued functions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc721269%28SQL.100%29.aspx) to get the information that you want.

Comment: I'll look into that. Do you know if it lets me check the keywords for a specific column? Also, how would you structure it? Using a many-to-many table?

Comment: @Jonathan - I can't remember many details of these functions and I haven't got Full Text set up on this machine the linked document has examples of their output though and it looks as though column is included. Yes I would use the many-to-many table.

Answer (score 1):

Why not to use separate table for tags with many-to-many relationship with tagged items table?
I mean something like that:

```
--Articles
ArticleId
Text

--Tags
TagId
Name

--TagsToArticles
ArticleRef
TagRef
```

Comment: A. Much more complex to add and remove tags, B. easy to get orphaned tags, C. Maybe slower because queries will involve more joins. This issue has been discussed many times on SO so I'm reluctant to debate the design here. Suffice to say I'm open to different ideas but have already researched the issue and am leaning a particular direction on this.

Comment: In my mind, such denormalization and usage of full-text search can affect your performance and increase code complexity much more than traditional normalized scheme.